# cannot format table properly

Tags: tabularx

```
\begin{table}[h]
\centering
\caption{Total Number of Each Tag in Our Gazetteer}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{cXc}
\toprule
\textbf{NER Tags} & \textbf{Number of Data} \\
\midrule
PER & 26,296 \\
CW & 20,446 \\
LOC & 16,617 \\
CORP & 13,737 \\
GRP & 10,517 \\
PROD & 6,136 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\label{tab:tagsingazz}
\end{table}
```

this is showing this[image: I c]

I want this
[image]

Comment: Why do you specify 3 columns (`cXc`) for a table with only two columns?

Comment: What eactly did you expect the table to look like?

Comment: @daleif refresh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to TeX.SE!

Huh, unusual demand :-). By use of the `tabularray` package with libraries ˙booktabs`and`siunitx`instead of`tabularx`, can be achieved the following result:

[image]

with quite simple table code.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs, siunitx}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[ht]
\caption{Total Number of Each Tag in Our Gazetteer}
\label{tab:tagsingazz}
\begin{tblr}{colspec = {X[l] X[c, si = {table-format=2.3}]},
             cell{2-Z}{1} = {cmd=\hspace{0.45\linewidth}},
             row{1}  = {guard, font=\bfseries, c}
             }       
    \toprule
NER Tags    &   Number of Data  \\
    \midrule
PER         & 26,296 \\
CW          & 20,446 \\
LOC         & 16,617 \\
CORP        & 13,737 \\
GRP         & 10,517 \\
PROD        &  6,136 \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tblr}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you. I love you bro. If you ever come in front of me, I will hold your hands and kiss you in your cheeks. You are the best angel. You are a gift to this world. May god bless you.

Comment: @sam5922, I'm old grumpy bear ... and allow only to nice females can kiss me .